# Ember.js In-template pattern to pass variable to a passed down action (contextual component)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to pass a variable into a passed down action and do so entirely in-template?

eg.
Parent Component Template

```
{{child-component model=model itemClick=(action "doStuffWithItem")}}
```

Child Component Template

```
{{#each model.items as |item|}}
   {{item-component click=(action itemClick item)}}
{{/each}}
```

..that doesn't work, but it shows an idea of the desired behaviour.

What I current have to do is make an action in `item-component` to trigger the passed down action with the variable.

eg. 
Parent Component.js

```
  actions: {
    doStuffWithItem(item) {
      ...do some things
    }
  }
```

Parent Component Template

```
{{child-component model=model itemClick=(action "doStuffWithItem")}}
```

Child Component.js

```
  actions: {
    click(item) {
      this.itemClick(item);
    }
  }
```

Child Component Template

```
{{#each model.items as |item|}}
   {{item-component itemClick=itemClick}}
{{/each}}
```

What I'm trying to ask, is there a way to skip creating the wrapper action in the child component.js? Is there an Ember helper where this just works? 
eg.

```
{{#each model.items as |item|}}
  {{item-component click=(pass-var-to-action itemClick item}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, [your first example works.](https://ember-twiddle.com/76d4d435af3d3c86179f74216566f9e4?openFiles=templates.components.child-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.child-component.hbs) So yes, its possible.

Your second example that you don't like however does not make sense. This code:

```
actions: {
  click(item) {
    this.itemClick(item);
  }
}
```

is not doing anything, because you dont use the `click` action inside the `child-component`.

It's totally unclear what your `item-component` does. Once you pass `click`, next `itemClick`. Be careful: *never* call a property `click`. This is a name collision with the `click` event handler method. See [here](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Component) under * Event Handler Methods*.
This is a bit an strange concept, but could be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the twiddle. The encompasses what I was trying to do.